# Golang http client is redirected to signin for bitbucket private url instead of giving auth failed

Tags: go, bitbucket

Trying to download a bitbucket private repo `https://bitbucket.org/md-shabbir/test-repo/get/master.tar.gz` with golang http client without providing any auth.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
)

func CheckRedirect(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
    fmt.Println("Redirect URL: ", req.URL)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    client := &http.Client{}
    client.CheckRedirect = CheckRedirect
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://bitbucket.org/md-shabbir/test-repo/get/master.tar.gz", nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
        return
    }
    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Status code: ", res.StatusCode)
}
```

Output:

```
Redirect URL:  https://bitbucket.org/account/signin/?next=/md-shabbir/test-repo/get/master.tar.gz
Redirect URL:  https://bitbucket.org/socialauth/login/atlassianid/?next=%2Fmd-shabbir%2Ftest-repo%2Fget%2Fmaster.tar.gz
Status code:  200
```

I am expecting the request should return http code **401** with **auth failed** but it is giving **200**.

However I tried to access the same url with curl, wget and python too and these all are giving expected return code **401**.

Answer (score 2):

Your client is redirected to the login page that returns a `StatusCode` of `200`.

The first hit is redirected (`302` with `Location: /account/signin/?next=/md-shabbir/test-repo/get/master.tar.gz`), and also the second one (`302 Found` with `Location: https://bitbucket.org/socialauth/login/atlassianid/?next=%2Fmd-shabbir%2Ftest-repo%2Fget%2Fmaster.tar.gz`).

This login page returns the status code of `200` which is the one you see.

If you don't want your client to follow these redirects, you could return a non-nil error from `CheckRedirect`.

I'm not sure if this will really solve the problem (as in BitBucket might still return `302`), but you could also not continue on *any* redirects to this URL and treat them as errors.

Answer (score -3):

```
If using https in Golange enable ssl , Try this below code like.

 http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}
    _, err := http.Get("https://bitbucket.org/md-shabbir/test-repo/get/master.tar.gz")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
```

Comment: bitbucket.org has a valid SSL certificate, you **absolutely should not disable SSL verification for this site**.